# overwritten inline styling still applies

Tags: css, reactjs, zoom-sdk

I am working on implementing zoom meetings to the website using zoom SDK. When implemented, it overwrote some of my styling, when I looked at the console, it showed that zoom SDK set min-width:1100px; I tried to overwrite it by using !important and inline styling. In the console, it shows that min-width:110px; is overwritten by my inline styling, but it still applies to the page.
How can I overwrite it?

Comment: you should provide more info or example,  because you can always manage css priority with parents or worst case using `!important`

Comment: `code`
element {
    min-width: 5px !important;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 643px;
    min-width: 1100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color: #4a4a4a;
}
`code`
So this is the code that I am talking about, in the console,min-width shows crossed,but when I toogle it,it still affects the website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you placed code for including sdk under your styling. If it's like this:

```
--style include
--sdk include
```

it should be

```
--skd include
--style include
```

One on bottom always overwrites one from above if they have same code.

Comment: My website is written in react, all my styling comes from styled-components.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body{
min-width:5px !important;
}
```

solved the problem, thank you all for your time and I will try to be more attentive before posting question :)